# unary numbers: base-1 numeral system

Tags: number-systems

We all are used to think that the lowest base for numeral system is <s>10</s> 2. But is it possible to do math in unary system?

I found the funny section in MS windows registry: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK88G.png
If you want to add monospace font to console font set, you must create entry wich name is filled with exact numbers of '0'. Is that example of unary numeral system?

But i have no idea how to write 'zero' or negaitve numbers in such a numeral system.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of zero is a relatively recent one - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero#History . There is no zero in unary.